# using "ar" put .o files into static library

Tags: macos, arm, unix-ar

The platform is mac osx, and the library's platform is arm64.

I have a static library which name is `arm64.a`.

Using `ar -x arm64.a`, I got some .o files.

And then I used `ar rcs libarm64.a *.o`, trying put all .o files into `libarm64.a`.

However, `arm64.a` and `libarm64.a` is not the same size.

`libarm64.a` is smaller than `arm64.a`.

I also tried to link `libarm64.a`, and linker complained `undefined reference xxx`.

Have I done wrong somewhere?

Comment: Is the result of `ar -t` the same for both archives?

Comment: @JeremyP It's not same. I find in `arm64.a` which is more bigger it contains two files identically named `list.o`. So `ar -x` maybe get only one file. Is it possible? Thanks.

Comment: The `ar -x` will overwrite the first instance of `list.o` with the second one because you might be able to put two files with the same name in a `.a` archive but you certainly can't have two files with the same name in a directory..